# Renaming groups in Jira

Tags: jira

How to rename groups in Jira? I am finding difficult to rename groups in jira. I already tried renaming groups in Jira. But it is not updating in created by and assigned dropdowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rename groups via SQL since there is no option from the web admin interface to do so. See this solution provided by the Atlassian community:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Questions/Need-to-rename-group/qaq-p/378695

WARNING: make a backup of your database before any direct sql statement is executed! Changing the database directly is at your own risk. Also, renaming the group DOES NOT transfer membership, so the renamed group will be empty. If your group already has members, the simplest solution would be to:

- delete the group
- create a new one
- reassign users to the new group

Hope this helps!

Comment: If we delete group and create a new group,does it leads to loose any data.Or the data will still remain.